# How to align to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using [this](http://latex2png.com/) converter of latex to png. When I write the following:

```
0.625\cdot2=1 + 0.25 \\ 
0.25\cdot2=0 + 0.5 \\
0.5\cdot2=1
```

It aligns lines to the right:

[image]

How can I align it to the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{aligned}
& 0.625\cdot2=1 + 0.25\\ 
& 0.25\cdot2=0 + 0.5\\
& 0.5\cdot2=1\\
\end{aligned}
```

[image: left-aligned]

Answer (score 4):

That equation editor uses `eqnarray` to set the equation, so [avoid it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Perhaps use [a different online editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php):

```
\hspace*{-\parindent}
0.625 \cdot 2 &= 1 + 0.25 \\ 
0.25 \cdot 2 &= 0 + 0.5 \\
0.5 \cdot 2 &= 1
```

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
0.625 \cdot 2 &= 1 + 0.25 \\ 
0.25 \cdot 2 &= 0 + 0.5 \\
0.5 \cdot 2 &= 1
\end{align*}
```

[image]